# Books, notes or any other online resource for basics of functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

I work in the field of Statistics. My supervisor has asked me to go through the basic, foundational elements of Functional Analysis. I have about a week before I report to him. My preliminary knowledge in Mathematics includes real analysis (measure and integration), linear algebra and basics of metric-space topology. I'd much appreciate if someone can provide me a book / notes / video-lectures or any other resource to learn the basics of functional analysis in about a week of time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/214360/intuitive-functional-analysis-book. But expecting "learn the basics of functional analysis in about a week of time" is utterly unrealistic. "There is no royal road to Geometry. "

Answer (score 2):

OCW: [Introduction to functional analysis](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-102-introduction-to-functional-analysis-spring-2009/lecture-notes/).

[Lecture notes](http://math.mit.edu/~rbm/18-102-S15/) by Richard Melrose.

[More lecture notes](http://www.math.kit.edu/iana1/lehre/funcana2012w/media/fa-lecturenotes.pdf).

...